# How can I share one webdriver instance in my test classes in the suite? I use Selenium2 and Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

My code is like this:

```
class class1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def testListRolesTitle(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get("www.google.com")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
        asert...


class class2(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def testListRolesTitle(self):
        driver=self.driver
        driver.get("www.google.com")
        assert...

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

def suite():
    s1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(class1)
    s2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(class2)

    return unittest.TestSuite([s1,s2])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    run(suite())
```

When I ran the suite both of the test classes started a new firefox instance in setup methord.
My question is if it's possible to make the two test classed use the same firefox instance? 
I don't want to put them together in one class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a setup function that applies to the whole module instead of just to the class as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule).

In your case, that would be something like:

```
def setUpModule():
    DRIVER = webdriver.Firefox()

def tearDownModule():
    DRIVER.quit()
```

Note that `DRIVER` is a global variable in this case so that it's available to the objects of all classes.

Also, note that test case ordering might cause that your module setup functions are called multiple times as explained in the documentation:

> The default ordering of tests created by the unittest test loaders is to group all tests from the same modules and classes together. This will lead to setUpClass / setUpModule (etc) being called exactly once per class and module. If you randomize the order, so that tests from different modules and classes are adjacent to each other, then these shared fixture functions may be called multiple times in a single test run.

It think this example should make clear when each setup method/function is executed:

```
import unittest

def setUpModule():
    print 'Module setup...'

def tearDownModule():
    print 'Module teardown...'

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print 'Class setup...'

    def tearDown(self):
        print 'Class teardown...'

    def test_one(self):
        print 'One'

    def test_two(self):
        print 'Two'
```

The output from this is:

```
$ python -m unittest my_test.py

Module setup...
Class setup...
One
Class teardown...
.Class setup...
Two
Class teardown...
.Module teardown...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused.

Comment: You should have both test cases in the same class since they share setup/teardown code. The setup/teardown in the class will be executed for each test case and the setup/teardown in the module will be executed once for the whole module.

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot. But if I use setUpModule() and tearDownModule()
I must put the the two test classes into one file, is that right?

Comment: I find another way, using  --builtin--, and it works. Is this way OK? I'm a beginner to set up a Python + Selenium automation test framework.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you shouldn't modify `__builtin__`.

Comment: There are many categories and test class in different files in my test project. I want to share webdriver in these classes and modules so that I don't need to open and quit firefox in every test class or module.

Comment: If you need more generic initialization, then you can perform it manually in your test package `__init__.py` or use, for example, [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/) which provides support for [setUpPackage/tearDownPackage](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-packages) functions.

Comment: If I add __init__ in my testsuite can I remove the setup and teardown from each testcase which are in separate class?

Comment: Is so then what should the __init__  contain??